# How to check if an NSArray contains any object at a particular index?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

I am trying to check an **NSArray** if it **contains any object** at any **particular index** and upon checking it i want to **insert the object** at that particular index if it is empty. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NSArray` does not contain `nil` values; `objectAtIndex:` will never return `nil`. it is an error to add `nil` to the collection.

To accomplish your task, you could use a placeholder object such as `[NSNull null]` as well as querying the array's `count`. Of course, you will need an `NSMutableArray` to actually perform mutations (e.g. replace or insert).

On OS X, you could use `NSPointerArray` to represent a collection which contains `nil` elements.

---

**Example using NSNull:**

```
const NSUInteger idx = ...;
NSMutableArray * array = ...;

if ([NSNull null] == [array objectAtIndex:idx]) {
  [array replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:someObject];
}
```

Comment: Can u just post a sample code snippet on how to do this? Does this look something like this? for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++){if([arr objectAtIndex:i])NSlog(@"U have the object")}else{[arr insertObject:anObject atIndex:i];}}